# Predicting multiple outputs with individual models sharing a common input features with RandomforestRegressor

Tags: python, regression, random-forest

I am trying to predict a number of output featues with a common set on input features. I want to create individual models for each of my output feature.

Is there a way that I could do this effeciently rather than manually creating individual instances of the RandomforestRegressor for each of my output feature?

I tried combining the MultiOutputRegressor() of scikit-learn with Randomforest, but strangely the r2 scores of the individual featues on the test set obtained using MutiOutputRegressor() and manually creating models for each output feature are different.